# jQuery cropbox: cant move, and zooms too near

Tags: jquery, crop

has anybody ever had problem with this?

http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/

I did everything as suggested but I cant move the cropbox, and if I try to zoom in or out, it goes "very close" to the image

Comment: can you post your code or make fiddle to see and people will help you ?